# Google Chrome/Chromium is buggy on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: linux, flash, google-chrome, ubuntu, chromium

For some reason, ever since I installed Ubuntu 12.10 my Chromium doesn't work well, it's buggy concerning Flash and other random stuff. I tried installing Google Chrome (`google-chrome-stable`) instead of Chromium, also because the version is more recent than Chromium. Some stuff worked better in comparison to Chromium, like Flash, but now Facebook was all buggy and unusable (the site was literally falling apart as I was scrolling).

Is there a way for me to install Google Chrome on Ubuntu 12.10 without it being buggy? Is somebody experiencing a similar problem?

Comment: Next time, try http://askubuntu.com/. Stack Overflow is meant for programming questions.

Answer (score 2):

Installing `google-chrome-beta` from the Synaptic Package Manager worked for me.